# Values of structs changing when appending to array with protocol type

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol, and some structs that conform to it, basically in the format shown below. I'm facing an issue where if I append different structs to an array of type `[Protocol]`, the values of the structs are changing in a weird way. However, if I change the type of the array to `[Struct1]` or `[Struct2]`, and only append the appropriate types, there's no problem.

```
protocol Protocol {
    var id: String { get set }
    var name: String { get set }
}

struct Struct1: Protocol {
    var id: String = "1"
    var name: String = "Struct1"
    var uniqueProperty1: String = "uniqueProperty1"
}

struct Struct2: Protocol {
    var id: String = "2"
    var name: String = "Struct2"
    var uniqueProperty2: String = "uniqueProperty2"
}

var structs: [Protocol] = []
let struct1 = Struct1()
let struct2 = Struct2()
structs.append(struct1)
structs.append(struct2)
```

And I should add, the above code works as expected. It's my project that has a protocol and some structs however that are behaving strangely. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: If the posted code works then it will be difficult to help. You need to post code that actually demonstrates the issue. At least [edit] your question to clarify in what way the values are changing.

Comment: Thanks for being willing to help, I discovered the issue and posted an answer.

Comment: You still need to post details in your question that represent and actually describe the issue.

Comment: Should I just delete the question? I don't know how I can edit it because it turns out it was a problem with the `Variables View` of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you look at the value of an element within an array of type `[Protocol]` in the `Variables View` within the `Debug Area`, it's possible that it won't reflect that element's actual values.

Here's an example:

[image]

You can see that `itemsList` in `cards[2]` is `nil`, but when I print out the same value in the `Debugger Output` of the `Console`, it's not nil (has a length of 4):

```
(lldb) po (cards[2] as? RBListCard)?.itemsList?.count
▿ Optional<Int>
  - some : 4
```

I guess the moral of the story is don't trust the values that show up within the `Variables View`.